# EntityDataSource, ObjectDataSource: When is it appropriate to use each one of them?

Tags: asp.net, datasource

Someone has already asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555066/pros-and-cons-of-using-entitydatasource-vs-objectdatasource-in-entity-framework) on this matter. But, I'd like have to get more information. According the person who answered, the EntityDataSource has more features, sorting, filtering, ... than the ObjectDataSource.

From that should I infer that It more appropriate to use EntityDataSource at all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EntityDataSource` only if you are using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) for data access - it uses capabilities of underlying framework to support features such sorting, filtering etc.

If you are using your some other data access framework or own DB Access Layer then you don't have alternative other than using `ObjectDataSource` (or roll out your own implementation).